# How can I have same font and font-size everywhere?

Tags: fonts, unicode

I'm tired of the weird (seemingly) unpredictable font behavior not just in org-mode but also anywhere I use some unicode symbols. My setup is spacemacs and I'm looking for function that I can run on startup that will make all the text rendering use the same font and font-size... as if running in VTY

EDIT: setup: latest spacemacs + clojure layer with fancify symbols enabled
https://practicalli.github.io/spacemacs/install-spacemacs/fancify-symbols.html
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxQU2.jpg

Using font Inconsolata for Powerline

EDIT: proof that the character is included with the font https://i.stack.imgur.com/otoUc.png

Comment: Could you clarify the problem - e.g., provide a step-by-step recipe, preferably starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file), saying at each step what you see that you don't like/expect, and what you would prefer. "Weird...unpredictable" doesn't tell us what you mean.

Comment: I don't think starting with `emacs -Q` is necessary, but I otherwise agree with Drew: please provide some example of the undesirable font-size differences, because normally Emacs already tries to keep font-sizes equal except where someone specifically asked for it to be different.  Sometimes the problem is that the default font you use does not cover all the chars necessary so Emacs is forced to mix-and-match fonts and some fonts look bigger/smaller even when they officially use the same size.

Comment: I've been asked to do this before, and it is unrealistic for me to go such lengths to come up with some minimal replicable example of the problem, to solve a minor problem. I'd like it to be solved with _minimal_ effort. @Stefan the problem can be seen using clojure-mode with https://practicalli.github.io/spacemacs/install-spacemacs/fancify-symbols.html ... using Inconsolata for Powerline font, I believe it has all the chars ... https://imgur.com/RIgFtJO

Comment: @skrat: [ Please put the added information directly in your question rather than in comments ] I don't see any "mixed font sizes" in your imgur link, sorry.  Could you give more details.  Also, just posting a single picture (with text explanation pointing out where you see the size difference) should be sufficient (and preferable to a video, unless maybe the problem is time-dependent).

Comment: The font you're using does not have the lambda symbol so a different font is used to render it. As an alternative you can use a font with decent Unicode coverage, such as DejaVu Sans Mono. See also related question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44213/how-to-set-line-height-to-the-tallest-fonts-height-in-buffer-with-multiple-fonts , although there is no  real solution there either.

Comment: And there is another workaround if you want to keep using your font, see  https://github.com/cpitclaudel/monospacifier for details.

Comment: @contemplator see https://i.imgur.com/wq53hcr.png

Comment: So the Powerline version does have some symbols added. Note that the original does not have them, so this seems like a bug in the font itself.

Comment: @skrat: please remember that you're asking strangers to help you.  They're not asking for something unreasonable when they're asking for a minimally-reproducible example.  They're trying to help, and without more information, they can only guess.

Comment: wow, much comments :) @Dan yes of course I keep that in mind. That's also why I formulated the question such that it can be answered without replicating the local setup: ie. looking for a function that can be run on startup, and brute force set all the font sizes of all font sets and all characters to the same size (pt or px).

Comment: I've looked at the font (found here: https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/Inconsolata) and there is no Greek there either https://i.imgur.com/25Pa9BD.png . Can you check your font in FontForge too?

Comment: It sounds as if you think that Emacs is requesting different font sizes for the different fonts it uses. In my experience the problem is actually that, while Emacs requests the same font size for all its fonts, how big they actually look varies greatly. I swear! One font's 13pt is another's 16pt and Emacs doesn't know, it just blindly asks for 13pt every time. I've handled this by setting the `face-font-rescale-alist` variable to make the fonts I use look about the same size.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe that there is any way to turn off glyph fallbacks. Of course I could be wrong; this is supported only by a brief examination of the Emacs code.

I looked in `fontset.c` which has the code for this. Specifically, the function `fontset_find_font` searches a fontset for the font information for a specific character. It does take a boolean parameter which suppresses the search for a fallback font. This function's caller (`fontset_font`), however, always calls it with the boolean first false and then if that fails calls it again with it true.

I think you'll just have to search for a more complete font for Emacs to use.

Also, the character picker does font fallback as well. You'll want to use a font viewer rather than a character picker for this task.